# iOS 6 UISearchBar in UINavigationBar not work

Tags: ios6, ios7, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I put my search bar in the navigation bar with these code:

```
UISearchBar* searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
searchBar.delegate = self;
[searchBar setShowsSearchResultsButton:YES];
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
```

When I run the same code in iOS 7, it works as I want.

But the search bar cannot work in iOS 6: when I touch it, the keyboard doesnot appear; when I click the result list button in the search bar, nothing happens, too.
Help!

(The base SDK is iOS 7.0)

### Edit1

Solving the problem like this:
Just cover the search bar on the navigation bar.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
    // Left Cancel button.
    UIBarButtonItem *barbtnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbtnCancel;
    
    // Right Search button.
    UIBarButtonItem *barbtnSearch = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(search:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barbtnSearch;
    
    // Navigation bar.
    UINavigationBar* navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 44)];
    [navBar pushNavigationItem:self.navigationItem animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
    
    // Search bar.
    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(53, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH-53-53, 44)];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    [self.searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [self.searchBar setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
    [self.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search Something"];
    [self.searchBar setShowsSearchResultsButton:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
}
```

Comment: I got the same problem as well. Please let me know if you find any solution!

Comment: @Andree I deal with this issue with the edited code above, not an elegant way, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the search bar with a frame that is not CGRectZero.